# How can I make my chatbot talk first?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I made a chatbot using Unity3d and IBM watson-conversation.

It works pretty well just like my web workspace.

In my web workspace, chatbot talks to me by recognizing 'welcome'.

However In unity, I can't see the welcome text, so I made fake text to start conversation for a while, but I changed some of my progress and I want to make it talk first. How can I make chatbot talk first?

```
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Services.Conversation.v1;
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Utilities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

class Watson : MonoBehaviour{    
static Credentials credentials;
static Conversation _conversation;
void Start()
{
    credentials = new Credentials("xx-xx-xx-xx-xx", "xx", "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api");
  //  credentials.Url = "";
    _conversation = new Conversation(credentials);

}
static Action<string, ManagerChat.Feel, bool> Act;
public static void GoMessage(string _str,Action<string, ManagerChat.Feel,bool> _act)
{

    if (!_conversation.Message(OnMessage, "xx-xx-xx-xx-xx", _str))
        Debug.Log("ExampleConversation Failed to message!");

    Act = _act;
}

static bool GetIntent(Dictionary<string, object> respDict)
{
    object intents;
    respDict.TryGetValue("intents", out intents);

    object intentString = new object();

    object confidenceString = new object();

    foreach (var intentObj in (intents as List<object>))
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> intentDict = intentObj as Dictionary<string, object>;

        intentDict.TryGetValue("intent", out intentString);


        intentDict.TryGetValue("confidence", out confidenceString);
    }
    string str = intentString as string;

    if (str == "6사용자_마무리")
        return true;

    return false;

}

static string GetOutput(Dictionary<string, object> respDict)
{
    object outputs;
    respDict.TryGetValue("output", out outputs);

    object output;
    (outputs as Dictionary<string, object>).TryGetValue("text", out output);

    string var = (output as List<object>)[0] as string;

    return var;
}

static ManagerChat.Feel GetEntities(Dictionary<string, object> respDict)
{
    object entities;
    respDict.TryGetValue("entities", out entities);

    List<object> entitieList = (entities as List<object>);

    if(entitieList.Count == 0)
    {
        return ManagerChat.Feel.Normal;
    }
    else
    {
        object entitie;
        (entitieList[0] as Dictionary<string, object>).TryGetValue("value", out entitie);
        ManagerChat.Feel feel = ManagerChat.Feel.NONE;

        string str = entitie as string;

        switch (str)
        {
            case "Happy":
                feel = ManagerChat.Feel.Happy;
                break;
            case "Expect":
                feel = ManagerChat.Feel.Expect;
                break;
            case "Born":
                feel = ManagerChat.Feel.Born;
                break;
            case "Sad":
                feel = ManagerChat.Feel.Sad;
                break;
            case "Surprise":
                feel = ManagerChat.Feel.Surprise;
                break;
            case "Normal":
                feel = ManagerChat.Feel.Normal;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return feel;
    }
}

static void OnMessage(object resp, string data)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> respDict = resp as Dictionary<string, object>;

  bool flag = (GetIntent(respDict));

    string output = (GetOutput(respDict));

   ManagerChat.Feel feel = GetEntities(respDict);
  //      Debug.Log(resp);
  //      Debug.Log(data);
        Act(output,feel, flag);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed this [issue](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/issues/254). Now you can pass an empty string into the Conversation service to initiate a conversation.

```
//  Test initate with empty string
if (!_conversation.Message(OnMessage, _workspaceId, ""))
    Log.Debug("ExampleConversation", "Failed to message!");

private void OnMessage(object resp, string data)
{
    Log.Debug("ExampleConversation", "Conversation: Message Response: {0}", data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the same approach of sending a fake text to conversation? probably your app needs to check if theres a new session, send a fake text. Or better yet, your app just send your own welcome message without going to conversation.

Comment: I think it doesn't work becuz I can't reach my child node.. 
In web workspace I can jump to node to node but I can't in unity.
What do I have to add to get those?

Comment: Did u set the userid when sending the fake text?

Comment: Sorry.. i think it should be the conversation_id inside the context.. as i’m not sure how u use unity to send the message..